# gRPC grpc-status: 8

Tags: grpc, istio, kubernetes-ingress

I am having trouble egetting through with gRPC from external to istio-ingress on Kubernetes.

But I have come so fare, that I can get a respons 200. Now I expect that `HTTP/1.1` is curl not supporting http2.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/grpc
grpc-status: 8
grpc-message: malformed method name: "/ghw"
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 8
date: Thu, 03 May 2018 18:33:28 GMT
server: envoy
content-length: 0
```

The yaml setup is as following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: grpc-deployment
  labels:
    app: grpc
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grpc
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grpc
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: grpc
        image: local/gcd
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - name: grpc-port
          containerPort: 3000
          # protocol: HTTP2

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grpc-service
spec:
  # type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: grpc
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    name: grpc
    # protocol: HTTP2
    targetPort: 3000

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grpc-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "istio"
    # ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /ghw
        backend:
          serviceName: grpc-service
          servicePort: 3000
```

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer your question, but https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md is a curl-like replacement that will work for gRPC and is useful for debugging.

Comment: I think this tool is better https://github.com/njpatel/grpcc

Comment: what is the `curl` command you try to execute?

Comment: If you want a GUI Tool for testing gRPC, consider BloomRPC: https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc

Comment: Have you tried: https://kreya.app